# How to fine value of parameters using Kendall's tau in R

Tags: r, parameters, static-methods, correlation

By considering the transformed bivariate Gumbel copula family and by using the method of moment, I have calculated the Kendall's tau as a dependence measure between two parameters `a` and `b` .

By considering the value of kendall's tau is already known `K=0.1006`, I have fixed the value `a=0.1`, from one of the two parameters, then I have used the inverse function of kendall's, to find the value b of the other parameter.  For that, I created the following `R` code.

The following error message occurs:

> `Error in c(1, 3) : argument inutilisé (3)`

I don't know where it is exactly.

I also need to know how to calculate the `bias` and `rmse`, to evaluate the performance of CM's estimator.

```
    C=function(u,v,a,b){(((((u^(-a))-1)^b+((v^(-a))-1)^b)^(1/b))+1)^(-1/a)}   #Gumbel function
cden(u,v,a,b)=function(u,v,a,b){(((((u^(-a)) - 1)^b + ((v^(-a)) - 1)^b)^(1/b)) + 1)^(((-1/a) - 
    1) - 1) * (((-1/a) - 1) * ((((u^(-a)) - 1)^b + ((v^(-a)) - 
    1)^b)^((1/b) - 1) * ((1/b) * (((v^(-a)) - 1)^(b - 1) * (b * 
    (v^((-a) - 1) * (-a))))))) * ((-1/a) * ((((u^(-a)) - 1)^b + 
    ((v^(-a)) - 1)^b)^((1/b) - 1) * ((1/b) * (((u^(-a)) - 1)^(b - 
    1) * (b * (u^((-a) - 1) * (-a))))))) + (((((u^(-a)) - 1)^b + 
    ((v^(-a)) - 1)^b)^(1/b)) + 1)^((-1/a) - 1) * ((-1/a) * ((((u^(-a)) - 
    1)^b + ((v^(-a)) - 1)^b)^(((1/b) - 1) - 1) * (((1/b) - 1) * 
    (((v^(-a)) - 1)^(b - 1) * (b * (v^((-a) - 1) * (-a))))) * 
    ((1/b) * (((u^(-a)) - 1)^(b - 1) * (b * (u^((-a) - 1) * (-a)))))))} #it is the density of gumbels 
myfun=function(u,v,a,b){(C(u,v,a,b)*cden(u,v,a,b))}
Kendall=function(a,b){tt=function(a,b){integrate(function(y) { 
   sapply(y, function(y) {
     integrate(function(x) myfun(x,y,a,b), 0,1)$value
   }) }, 0, 1)$v}4*tt(a,b)-1}
a=0.1          #the value of one parameters
K=0.1006     #the value of kendall's tau
Kinv1 <- function(z) optimize(function(y) (z-(Kendall(a,y)))^2,c(1,3), tol=0.0001)$minimum      #the inverse function of kendall's
Kinv1(K)

Error in c(1, 3) : argument inutilisé (3)
```

**Edit**

```
C <- function(u, v, a, b) {
  # Gumbel function
  (((((u ^ (-a)) - 1) ^ b + ((v ^ (-a)) - 1) ^ b) ^ (1 / b)) + 1) ^ (-1 / a)
}

myfun <- function(u, v, a, b) {
  (C(u, v, a, b) * cden(u, v, a, b))
}

Kendall <- function(a, b) {
  tt <- function(a, b) {
    integrate(function(y) {
      sapply(y, function(y) {
        integrate(function(x)
          myfun(x, y, a, b), 0, 1)$value
      })
    }, 0, 1)$v
  }
  4 * tt(a, b) - 1
}

a <- 0.1    # the value of one parameters
K <- 0.1006 # the value of kendall's tau

Kinv1 <- function(z) {
  # the inverse function of kendall's
  optimize(function(y) (z - (Kendall(a, y))) ^ 2, c(1, 3), tol = 0.0001)$minimum
}

Kinv1(K)
```

> Error in cden(u, v, a, b) : could not find function "cden"

Comment: your original code does not run, but I get the error above with formatted code

Comment: Is there a reason why you calculate Gumel and Kendall tau manually (using your own code). You can find them using VineCopula package.